# Is it possible to to handle invalid JSON values globally using Serde / Rust?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

What I mean by that is the following:

Given this struct:

```
struct SomeObj {
  someProp: bool
}
```

Is there a way to force Serde to assign true / false to `someProp` when its value is NOT boolean in the JSON input?

Normally, serde would just return an error in such cases (invalid type, expected XY..etc). But would it be possible to suppress the error and just provide some meaningful default value instead?

I know this is possible doing something like:

```
#[serde(from = "serde_json::Value")]
struct SomeObj {
  someProp: bool
}

impl From<serde_json::Value> for SomeObj {
...
}
```

But there there are a huge number of complex and large structs I need to deal with, so handling this globally would be much easier.

Comment: Do you want to accept some other type, e.g. a string `"yes"` or `"no"`, and convert it to bool?

Comment: No. I want to convert every type that's not boolean to false.

Comment: In other words I want serde to accept true or false and everything else should be converted to boolean false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always override `serde`'s choice of deserializer with the attribute [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with). This attribute accepts a function that will be used to deserialize, in place of the usual `Deserialize` trait.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeObj {
  #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_bool_or_false")]
  someProp: bool
}

fn deserialize_bool_or_false<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<bool, D::Error>
where D: Deserializer<'de> {
  let deserialized = bool::deserialize(deserializer);
  // deserialized is a Result<bool, ...>. You can handle the error
  // case however you like. This example simply returns false.
  Ok(deserialized.unwrap_or(false))
}
```

You just need to attach that `deserialize_with` attribute to every field that you want the custom defaulting behavior on.

If you're willing to pull in an extra dependency, the [`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/index.html) library has [`DefaultOnError`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.DefaultOnError.html), which returns the [`Default::default()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) value for a type (that's `false`, `""`, `0`, `0.0`, etc.) if any deserialization error occurs on that field. So with that structure, you can mark *any* field as `#[serde_as(deserialize_as = "DefaultOnError")]` and, provided the underlying type implements the trait `Default`, it'll just work.

```
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeObj {
  #[serde_as(deserialize_as = "DefaultOnError")]
  someProp: bool
}
```

This will work on `bool`, any signed or unsigned integer type, floating-point types, strings, and anything that satisfies `Default`.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds much better than implementing From for each and every struct / enum. But I guess this still means I have to create a bunch of custom deserializers and then attach them to each field manually. 
So there is no "easy way" around this, right? Like somehow telling serde how to handle bool, string, number etc fields once and then just use that everywhere.

Comment: @user2297996 Check out the edit I just made to the answer. I was thinking `serde_with` could do this cleanly, and I found it. `DefaultOnError` should work for pretty much any reasonable JSON type, as long as the "default" value you want is the one defined by Rust's `Default` trait.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this sounds great! I'll do this.